Add attachments and Embed Image in Email body PowerApps
I am trying to utilise Office365Outlook.SendEmail but having issues passing attachments and embedding an image in to the body of the email.
Firstly, I have an attachment control DataCardValue4 that I am unable to pass to the function successfully.
Secondly, I am trying to build the email body using elements from my app. The main thing that I am trying to achieve is to embed an image that is collected from a Pen Input.
I am looking to build the body of the email using:
Input_Summary.text
Input_Name.text
PenInput1.Image
DatePicker1.SelectedDate
My main focus is how to successfully get the pen Input into the email body as PenInput.The image gives me a blob text string.

Following is a way, by which you can attach input from PenInput:
Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2( 
   "Sample@sample.com",
   "Sample Subject",
   "Sample Body",
   {    Attachments: Table({
            Name: "image.jpg",
            ContentBytes: PenInput1.Image
        })
    }
)

